# high stocks turbothreshhold issue in Two panes, candlestick and volume with flags

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, highcharts

I had created the charts with flags and without flags,

But when I used the data with flags(news related info),it is not showing if have more data,that's why I used turbo threshold option  like below.

```
plotOptions: {
  candlestick: {
    color: '#ef2d24',
    upColor: '#72b74c'
  },
  area: {
    color: {
      linearGradient: {
        x1: 0,
        y1: 0,
        x2: 0,
        y2: 1
      },
      stops: [
        [0, '<%=m_sStartColor%>'],
        [1, '<%=m_sEndColor%>']
      ]
    }
  },
  ohlc: {
    color: '#ef2d24',
    upColor: '#72b74c'
  },
  column: {
    color: '#20b1be'
  },
  series: {
    turboThreshold: 5000,
    dataGrouping: {
      enabled: true,
      units: [
        ['day', [1]], // unit name
        ['week', [1]], // allowed multiples          
        ['month', [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]] // unit name
      ]
    },
    cursor: 'pointer'
  },
  flags: {
    events: {
      mouseOver: function() {
        this.chart.flagTooltip = true;
      },
      mouseOut: function() {
        this.chart.flagTooltip = false;
      }
    },
    tooltip: {

      shared: true,
      width: 700
    }

  }
}
},
series: [{
  type: '<%=m_sType %>',
  name: 'Stock Price',
  id: 'dataseries',
  data: ohlc,
  dataGrouping: {
    units: groupingUnits
  },
  tooltip: {
    valueDecimals: 3
  },
  marker: {
    enabled: false,
    radius: 3
  },
  visible: true,
  threshold: null

}, {
  type: 'column',
  name: 'Volume',
  data: volume,
  yAxis: 1,
  dataGrouping: {
    units: groupingUnits
  }
}]

}
```

But when I used turbo threshold option volume figures showing double(means wrong data).How to get rid of the issue.
Here I am attaching both images.Please let me know how to get rid of the issue.

Volume doubled
[image: Volume doubled]

Actual data:
[image: Actual data]

Comment: Can you make a live example, e.g. on jsfiddle? Do you mean trheshold or turboThreshold? In the demo https://jsfiddle.net/kr9hjjv2/ turboThreshold does not affect columns.

Comment: hi..I am sending the URLs both [Without News](http://insage.com.my/ir/cmn/trps02/InteractiveStockCharts.aspx?Symbol=5216&Adjusted=Yes&ChartType=area)  and [with News](http://insage.com.my/ir/cmn/trps02/InteractiveStockCharts_News.aspx?Symbol=5216&Adjusted=Yes&ChartType=area) you can see the news one volume figures difference without selections any announcement. after selecting any of the announcements it is showing correct figures. with out news one is showing correct figures. Please help me on the above issue.

Comment: Read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and paste the full and minimal code or try to create a live example, e.g. on jsfiddle.